# Run Jest unit test with TFS 2015

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, visual-studio-2015, tfsbuild, jestjs

Has anyone attempted to integrate jest unit tests with TFS 2015? I tried to use Chutzpah Test Adapter (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f8741f04-bae4-4900-81c7-7c9bfb9ed1fe?SRC=VSIDE) however it's not able to recognize jest. I receive below error:
[Can't find variable Jest](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nVDOQ.jpg)

When I run the unit tests through "npm test" I get the results. However to integrate with TFS 2015 I need a test runner which can run Jest unit test so that I can run the unit tests in conjunction with vstest.console.exe which the TFS 2015 provides so it can manage build results and publish results in the build summary report.

Any help would be appreciated!!

Any test runner which can run tests using below command should work (considering VS 2015 installed on the system):
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TestWindow\vstest.console.exe" "\test.js" /UseVsixExtensions:true

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720050/how-to-publish-jest-unit-test-results-in-vsts-tests if that answer works for you.

Answer (score 7):

Extending on [Merlin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38422707/1069189), here is how I've implemented publishing jest test results AND code coverage to TFS2015 vNext builds (I am using create-react-app boilerplate):

First install required packages on the Server you are running your Agent on:

npm install -g jest-json-to-tap

npm install -g tap-xunit

1. configure jest to output json, by changing in package.json the "test" task to:
   "test": "react-scripts test --env=jsdom --json",
2. configure jest options in package.json:
   "jest": { "coverageReporters": ["cobertura"] }
3. created a vNext build (TFS2015v4) with the following tasks:

a. "npm" task, command=run, arguments=test -- --coverage | jest-json-to-tap | tap-xunit > TEST-result.xml

b. "publish test results" task, format=JUnit

c. "public code coverage results" task, code coverage tool=Cobertura, Summary file=$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\coverage\cobertura-coverage.xml

4. make sure your build's "Variables" include setting the environment variable "CI"="true"

NOTES:
- test results will not include times nor assemblies - something to extend for the future...

Voila'! Running this build will correctly publish the test results and code coverage stats, as well as report artifacts.

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about jest, but there's a neat npm package that can convert TAP based results to xUnit XMLformat, and then you can publish that to TFS.

Take a look at [tap-xunit](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tap-xunit).

I had a build environment where javascript testing was done by various tools and frameworks (AVA, Mocha, Jasmine etc). We decided to export them all to TAP format, run them throw tap-xunit and then publish to TFS.

Basically, you need something like this:

```
npm test | tap-xunit > results.xml
```

You pipe the results to tap-xunit and save them to an XML. This gives you an XML formatted as xUnit that you can publish to TFS. If you're running TFS 2015, I strongly recommend going with vNext builds, a lot easier to get these running. Check the "Publish Test Results" build step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running with XAML build, this link will help you: [Javascript Unit Tests on Team Foundation Service with Chutzpah](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2012/07/09/javascript-unit-tests-on-team-foundation-service-with-chutzpah/)

If you are running with vNext build, please try the detail steps mentioned with Jasmine.JS test(also a kind of JavaScript test ) in [this blog](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/developers/articles/week04aug15/nunit-and-jasmine-js-unit-tests-in-tfs-vso-vnext-build/).