# Failed to parse result files when VSTest is run Azure pipelines

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, vstest

I have added the below steps to run unit test in Azure pipelines for React UI.

Added a file , File name:jestTrxProcessor.js. The content:

```js
var builder = require("jest-trx-results-processor/dist/testResultsProcessor"); 
var builder = require("jest-trx-results-processor");
 
var processor = builder({
  outputFile: "jestTestresults.trx", 
});
 
module.exports = processor;
```

2. In package.json I entered the below code:

```
"scripts": {
....
"test": "jest"
},
devdependencies{
 ...
 "jest": "^23.4.1",
  "jest-trx-results-processor": "0.0.7",
  "jsdom": "^11.12.0"
},
"jest": {
       "testResultsProcessor": "./__tests__/jestTrxProcessor.js",
    "reporters": [
"default",
[
  "jest-trx-results-processor",
  {
    "outputFile": "./__tests__/jestTestresults.trx",
  
  }
]]},
```

3.In the yaml file I added the below script:

```
- script: |
    npm install
    npm install jest-trx-results-processor --save-dev
    yarn add --dev jest-trx-results-processor
    npm run build
 
   # npm run test
  displayName: 'npm install and build'
  
- task: PublishTestResults@2
  inputs:
    testResultsFormat: 'VSTest'
    testResultsFiles: './__tests__/jestTestresults.trx'
    testRunTitle: 'FrontEnd Test'
```

I am getting the below error:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Failed to parse result files when VSTest is run Azure pipelines

According to the error message:

> Publish Test Results Failed to parse result files:
> System.Xml.XmlException: Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1,
> position 1

It means that you have attempted to parse something that is not an XML document or there is a issue with the generated trx file.

To troubleshooting this issue, please try to update the devdependencies `jest` `jest-trx-results-processor`:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jest-trx-results-processor": "~2.0.0"
  },
```

And try to select `JUnit` in `TestResultsFormat`:

[image]

Besides, the [Jest testResultsProcessor property is deprecated](https://github.com/jest-community/jest-junit/issues/56#), please try to use the jest-junit package for test reports:

Please check [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51720050/how-to-publish-jest-unit-test-results-in-vsts-tests/52357797#52357797) for some more details.